# How to start tikzpicture on top-left of page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've starting using TiKZ, just 2 days ago, and I found it beautiful. I've already used `\scope`, `\node` etc.

My problem is:
How can I start the picture from the upper left corner of the page?

I looked at some syntax guide of TikZ, but I didn't find it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You may use the special `current page` node ([p.250, pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=250)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `current page` node, either in a drawing or in positioning a drawing.

I will show how to position a drawing to the top left corner of a page, using a node which contains a TikZ drawing. The benefit is, that the inner picture doesn't need to know about the page position at all.

A specialty is, that nodes of the inner drawing inherit options, such as the anchor, from the parent node. So see, how I took care: I stated the node anchor style in the inner drawing, even if center is the default.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, transform shape]
  \node [anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt]
    at (current page.north west)
    {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
        \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
          \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
          \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
          \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
        \end{scope}
        \node at ( 90:2)    {Typography};
        \node at ( 210:2)   {Design};
        \node at ( 330:2)   {Coding};
        \node [font=\Large] {\LaTeX};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output at the page corner]

I took the example from my upcoming [LaTeX book](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook), as it was easy for me to grab from my hard disk.

Comment: when i run the code Feb 2021 in Overleaf, the result is different from the picture, the transparency seems not to work

Comment: @Mandragor That's a fault of the Overleaf PDF preview function. Click in "Download PDF" on Overleaf and use the Acrobat Reader or another PDF reader to see the transparancy.

Comment: Why do we need `every node/.append style = {anchor=center}`?

Comment: @alper That's because the `north west` anchor would be inherited, as I briefly mentioned in the answer. Adding (again) the `center` anchor fixes it. Remove it to see what I mean.